# Is there a configuration in Kafka to write multiple records to one S3 object?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, data-pipeline

I'm using an S3 Sink Connector to write records to S3 from Kafka. Eventually I will be using Kafka to capture CDC Packets from my Database and then writing these packets to S3.

However, I don't want every single CDC Packet, which in Kafka will be a single record, to be written to a separate S3 Object. I would want to configure a size or time based condition so that all records every X seconds or Y bytes are written to one S3 object.

I haven't been able to find any thing that would write records to one object, however I have found Kafka Consumer properties `fetch.min.bytes` and `fetch.max.wait.ms` which do write the objects every X seconds or Y bytes - but multiple records are still written as separate objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use a basic consumer for this (I mean, you could, but then you'd obviously need to write all "batching" logic you're requesting yourself).

The S3 **Kafka Connect** sink already does this via `flush.size` (record count, not bytes), and/or time-based partitioner.

The Secor project is also something to look at.